# time difference between two date removing closing time

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

my company has numbers of shops around all the locations. They raised a request for delivering the item to their shop which they can sell . We wanted to understand how much time the company takes to deliver the item in minutes.However, we don't want to add the time in our elapsed time when the shop is closed i.e.

lets consider shop opening and closing time are

[image]

now elapsed time

[image]

When I deduct complain time and resolution time then I get `calculatable elasped time in minutes` but I need Required `elapsed time in minutes` so in the first case out of 2090 minutes those minutes are deducated when shop was closed. I need to write an oracle query to calcualted the `required elapsed time in minutes` which is in green.

help what query we can write.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: Please show the query you are using to get the gross elapsed time. Then we can build on this to get the net elapsed time.

Comment: How do you get 1430 minutes? The complaint is raised when the shop is closed. So the first day we only count the last two hours of the day when the shop is open again. The next day we count the nine hours until 9:00. Then the shop is closed again. And the case is resolved before it opens once more. This makes (2 + 9) * 60 = 660 minutes. Have I misunderstood the request?

Comment: shop 1 open at 09:00 AM and complain raised at 10:12 so this is during the working hour, so the first day its total 708 minutes request was open and second day before closing it took 722 minutes which is total 1430 minutes to actually closing it.

Comment: Please show the query you are using to get the gross elapsed time. Tan we can build on this to get the net elapsed time.: This is calculated in excel, looking for oracle sql query.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, you are right of course. I confused opened and closed times.

Comment: How do you store opening and closing time? Oracle doesn't have a `TIME` data type.

Comment: its symbolic, this is an example table.

Answer (score 0):

One formula to get the net time is as follows:

- For every day involved add up the opening times. For your first example this is two days 2021-01-11 and 2021-01-12 with 13 daily opening hours (09:00 - 22:00). That makes 26 hours.
- If the first day starts after the store opens, subtract the difference. 10:12 - 09:00 = 1:12 = 72 minutes.
- If the last day ends before the store closes, subtract the difference. 22:00 - 21:02 = 0:58 = 58 minutes.

Oracle doesn't have a `TIME` datatype, so I assume you are using Oracle's datetime data type they call `DATE` to store the opening and closing time and we must ignore the date part. And you are probably using the `DATE` type for the complain_time and the resolution_time, too.

In below query I convert the time parts to minutes right away, so the calculations get a tad more readable later.

```
with s as
(
  select
    shop,
    extract(hour from opening_time) * 60 + extract(minute from opening_time) as opening_minute,
    extract(hour from closing_time) * 60 + extract(minute from closing_time) as closing_minute
  from shops
)
, r as
(
  select 
    request, shop, complain_time, resolution_time,
    trunc(complain_time) as complain_day,
    trunc(resolution_time) as resolution_day,
    extract(hour from complain_time) * 60 + extract(minute from complain_time) as complain_minute,
    extract(hour from resolution_time) * 60 + extract(minute from resolution_time) as resolution_minute
  from requests
)
select
  r.request, r.shop, r.complain_time, r.resolution_time,
  (r.resolution_day - r.complain_day + 1) * 60
  - case when r.complain_minute > s.opening_minute) then r.complain_minute - s.opening_minute else 0 end
  - case when r.resolution_minute < s.opening_minute) then s.closing_minute - r.resolution_minute else 0 end
    as net_duration_in_minutes
  from r
join s on s.shop = r.shop
order by r.request;
```